# Questions on Facebook Pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm basically a beginner to Facebook's graph API

At present, I'm looking for programmatically read get data about no.of users who answered a question on a Facebook page that I admin.

I went through a few links like this : https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/596/ where they are asking for an APP ID and APP Secret.

My question is, Do I actually need an APP ID and APP Secret?
I do not want to create a Facebook app, I just want to access data from questions asked on a facebook page.

Thanks!

Comment: To query the API for all but the most basic data, you need a Facebook app.

Comment: So in that case, will my users also have to use the app? 
Or my page alone can use the app for getting the data?

Comment: It depends. If the data you are getting does not require a user access token, then you can authenticate as the app, and retrieve the data without your app ever interacting with a user. If the data you are requesting requires a user access token, then users will have to authorize and authenticate against your app.

Comment: I accessed questions from the Facebook page through an app. App ID and App Secret were wanted though. Thanks.